# passing complex object into mvc controller action from javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass an object into my mvc controller action and return a list of values but im having some difficulties, can anyone see where Im going wrong ?

Heres my javascript

```js
var model = { MainOrganisation : frmOrg.elements["Schedule_OrgId"].value,
                ContractRefs: $.map($('#js_multiselect_to_1 option'), function (ele) { return ele.value; })
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                url: '/ReportScheduler/GetReportUsers',
                data: model,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    //Do Stuff
                    $("#DailyInvoiceItems").html(data.Id);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //Do Stuff or Nothing
                }
            });
```

and this is the action method on my controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetReportUsers(ReportUserRequest request)
    {
        GetUserRequest userRequest = new GetUserRequest(request.MainOrganisation);
        var userResponse = await this._userService.GetAllUsersForOrgAsync(userRequest);

        return Json(userResponse.users, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

the model im passing in is structured  like this

```
public class ReportUserRequest
{
    public int MainOrganisation { get; set; }
    public List<string> ContractRefs { get; set; }
    public ReportUserRequest()
    {
        this.ContractRefs = new List<string>();
        this.MainOrganisation = 0;
    }
}
```

The ajax call jumps into the controller action but when I inspect the object, only the MainOrganisation has a value, the list is null, but I have checked on the clientside and it is populated with values so theyre being 'lost' somewhere

Comment: Is the $.map correct? can you the return into a variable and check the content?

Comment: Agred with @tire0011 - check the $.map result - it looks like it should be `$('#js_multiselect_to_1 option').map(function() { return $(this).val(); });`  add `console.dir(model)` before the ajax call and check console (edit: looks like you already checked, but check the type of the list).

Comment: Also, check the browser network tab, it will show you the full url that $.ajax created from the model (as it's a GET) and you can right-click it and open in new tab to inspect.

Comment: your map schould be: $('#js_multiselect_to_1 option').map(function(index,el){return el.value}). The second value is the element

Comment: I changed the controller method signature and it worked   [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> GetReportUsers(ReportUserRequest request)
        {